# comparing dates mysql

Tags: mysql, string-comparison, date-comparison

i am having a litle problem with my sql query.

in database i have a expiry date for a invoice.

is saved as string 12-01-2013

now i want to compare this date with today. but is not working.

this is de code.

include_once('config/connect.php');

connectdb();

```
$name = $_GET['name'];

$date = date('d-m-Y');

$qry = "SELECT *, finished_invoice.date AS invoice_date FROM finished_invoice
    INNER JOIN customer 
    ON finished_invoice.customer = customer.customer_nr 
        WHERE finished_invoice.user = '".$_SESSION['id']."' 
    AND customer.company_name = '$name'
    AND expiry_date < '$date'
    AND finished_invoice.sent > '0'
    AND finished_invoice.paid = '0'   
    ORDER BY finished_invoice.id DESC"
```

if anybody can help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: If it's a date, then save it in your db as a date... It will make comparisons like this a lot easier!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing the date object use strtotime() function to compare as string

Comment: Thnx for helping me out guys.

i found a way to resolve this problem

i changed database string from dd-mm-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

and my data var to date('Y-m-d'); and now is working ok.

i had to change date from datebase when i was showing it in my text but that was easy 
with exolode function.

Comment: @NamirDžilić Post your answer and then accept it as well. It will help Stackoverflow and its users.

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing PHP date format d-m-y with mysql format y-m-d thats why you are getting problem.
Try using this :

```
   SELECT *, finished_invoice.date AS invoice_date FROM finished_invoice
        INNER JOIN customer 
        ON finished_invoice.customer = customer.customer_nr 
            WHERE finished_invoice.user = '".$_SESSION['id']."' 
        AND customer.company_name = '$name'
        AND expiry_date < STR_TO_DATE($date, '%d-%m-%Y')
        AND finished_invoice.sent > '0'
        AND finished_invoice.paid = '0'   
        ORDER BY finished_invoice.id DESC
```

Comment: my date in databese is saved as string 12-01-2013 en my date is also a string from $date = date('d-m-Y');